# TinyMce Paste plugin word content paste not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, tinymce

I am using tinymce with jquery and enabled paste plugin to copy paste content from word documents.

But after pasting content and doing some formatting, this saved text does not show up well in IE.

It seems that tinymce adds following html code in it, removing which it works well with IE.

```
<p>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <w:WordDocument> <w:View>Normal</w:View> <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom> <w:PunctuationKerning /> <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas /> <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid> <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent> <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText> <w:Compatibility> <w:BreakWrappedTables /> <w:SnapToGridInCell /> <w:WrapTextWithPunct /> <w:UseAsianBreakRules /> <w:DontGrowAutofit /> </w:Compatibility> <w:BrowserLevel>MicrosoftInternetExplorer4</w:BrowserLevel> </w:WordDocument> </xml><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" LatentStyleCount="156"> </w:LatentStyles> </xml><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte mso 10]> <mce:style><!   /* Style Definitions */  table.MsoNormalTable  {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";     mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;  mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;  mso-style-noshow:yes;   mso-style-parent:"";    mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;    mso-para-margin:0in;    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;    font-size:10.0pt;   font-family:"Times New Roman";  mso-ansi-language:#0400;    mso-fareast-language:#0400;     mso-bidi-language:#0400;} --> <!--[endif] -->
</p>
```

so my question is -- can I configure tinymce somehow to not add above lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following tinymce init parameters

```
    paste_strip_class_attributes : "all",
    paste_remove_styles: true,
    paste_convert_middot_lists: false,
```